# subtracting elements in an array from elements in another array

Tags: arrays

I am given an assignment where a user hypothetically inputs values into array 1 and array 2.

My job is to declare an additional array of five doubles, find the new array with the difference between the corresponding elements in the array 1 and array 2 and then print the values stored in the new array to the screen.

I have NO idea how to do this, I've been stuck for an hour. could you please help? thank you so much

Comment: This is my guess

Comment: If performance is a non factor for you just do two nested loops where you iterate through both arrays

Comment: @j0h4nn3s would this be correct

Comment: public class test
{
    double []a1 = new double[5];
    double []a2 = new double [5];
    double []a3=new double[5]; 
{for(int i=0;i<5;i++) a3[i]=a1[i]-a2[i]; 
}
{for(int i=0;i<5;i++)System.out.println(a3[i]);
}
}

Comment: yeah someone answered the exact same below its correct

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume the two arrays are the same length(and that length is 5), it's straightforward enough. Use a loop to access the corresponding values and put the result in the corresponding position of the result array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] arrA = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};
        double[] arrB = {5.0,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0};
        double[] result = new double[5];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++){
          result[i] = arrA[i] - arrB[i];
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[-4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```